# List view threshold error even when using indexed column filter

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, view, threshold

I have migrated a WSS 3.0 farm to SP Foundation 2013. One list has 6500 items. No view will display unless I raise the threshold to > 6500. Test view is filtered on one indexed column that displays only 3700 items when the threshold is raised. When I lower the threshold back to 5000 it fails with the standard threshold exceeded message. I have no sorting or grouping in the test view.

I have searched endlessly and all research says that this view should work. What am I missing? I migrated the list items and then created the indexed columns. Shouldn't that have worked? The list has been added to extensively since the original migration. I have deleted and recreated the indexed column. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the full crawl from central admin?

Comment: I assume you mean search crawls? Yes, it is crawled every day. I'm not sure how that will affect the issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just making sure you have performed full crawl efter you have added columns to index? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Have a similar problem... Did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple filters in that view? If so, make sure that the indexed columns is the first filter, otherwhise it will fail on the column that is not indexed.

Comment: No, the view that I'm testing with only has the one filter column which is in the first place, of course, and is indexed.